# How to override a boilerplate style

Tags: css, stylus

I have the following style in a stylesheet that I do not want to edit:

```
.dbootstrap .dgrid .dgrid-row:hover,
.dbootstrap .dgrid .dgrid-row:hover .dgrid-cell {
    background-color: #1ebafb;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

The effect of the style is to overlay a textbox and hide the typing that go in there. My code works when that style is that there but I do not want to edit the third party file for maintenance reasons.

Is there any maintainable way to remove the style? I am using stylus to generate my css stylesheet.

EDIT: I realize that I have not done a very good job of explaining. I don't think that I can just change the property values - at least I cannot find values that allow the typed text to show (I tried setting the background color to transparent). I found that if I remove the ":hover" style all together, the typing shows. It is difficult to find out exactly what is going on as the control is dynamic and it is a hover style on top of that.

Comment: Ovveride these css in your own css file or inline style

Comment: I cannot find override values that make it go away. I can only make it work when it is removed. So "override" was not a correct description.

Comment: ok, try removing the class form the overlay element.

Comment: Do you mean you want to reset some of the CSS props? And you cannot find the correct value to reset them?